# Display Monitor Times Out and Locks Too Fast/Independent of Relevant Settings

Tags: windows-10, display, timeout

My system: Windows 10 64-bit Home Edition + Acer SB220Q Monitor.

I hooked up a new monitor last week...my old monitor behaved just fine/as I intended.

Despite the relevant settings being set to what I want ("Power & Sleep": Screen = 20 minutes; Sleep = 30 minutes), and re-adjusted, rebooted, and set back to original settings, my screen blacks out in about 1 minute of inactivity and locks after about 2 minutes.  The monitor does not seem to have any adjustments/buttons that affect this behavior.  Are there other settings, e.g. arcane registry tweaks, which may help with this?

Comment: Have you also checked the settings of Power Options under Control Panel\Hardware and Sound. Or maybe you can run the Power troubleshooter to diagnose (Control Panel>View by Large icons>Troubleshooting>View all>Power). For more solutions, you can refer to this link https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-sleep-too-fast/

Comment: @seven: I checked out the link and tried several of the options but no luck (to be clear, this is all/only about my monitor's behavior, not my computer/CPU sleeping).  It also occurred to me to review the hardware driver: the current one was make/model specific, so I tried the generic PnP monitor driver as well...no change in behavior, monitor keeps locking then blacking out after only a minute or three of idle.  Sigh...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the screensaver setting.  I have never used a screen saver, preferring the screen just to go dark.  Somehow, and I don't understand how, either installing new driver or simply switching to HDMI for control did something, or possibly Windows Update did something that was coincident in time with my new monitor being hooked up, or HDMI controller signals handle that setting different than VGA, or...?  Anyhoo...mischief managed, case solved, mission accomplished, cookie crumbled, drop the mike, over and out!